# Payment Gateway Pop-up Not Showing in Android Emulator with VPN and Location Set to South Africa

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Why isn't a region-specific payment gateway appearing in my Android emulator when I'm using a VPN set to South Africa and have also set the emulator's location to South Africa, despite being based outside of South Africa?

The payment gateway works on android devices in South Africa.